# How to follow symlinks in NFS?

Tags: symlink, nfs

I have different disks with pictures

```
/media/drive1/pictures/
/media/drive2/pictures/
/media/drive3/pictures/
/media/drive4/pictures/
# ...
```

I have a folder called **share** which has symlinks for *every* subfolder of each *pictures* directory of each drive. I merge every subfolder with a script like this:

```
# I do this for every drive
for item in "/media/drive1/pictures/"*
do
    target=/media/share/pictures/`basename "$item"`
    if [ ! -d "$target" ]; then
        ln -s "$item" "$target"
        chown -h lsc:lsc "$target"
    fi
done
```

I've been sharing this successfully with Samba for a whlle now.

```
[global]
# ...
follow symlinks = yes
```

Since this is a pure private network and the share is READONLY, security isn't a big deal.

```
### /etc/exports
/media/share *(ro,async)
```

When I mount my share `mount 1.2.3.4:/ foo` the symlinks try to follow on the local host.

**My question:** How can I share a folder that follows symlinks *on* the host that's sharing the mount?

**NOTE:** The `bind bind` solution in `/etc/fstab` won't work here, since every subfolder of `/media/share/` points to different locations/disks.

Comment: Why would be `bind` mount not work? Did you try to add `crossmnt` to your `/etc/exports` and restart the NFS server, then remount.

Answer (score 6):

Why can't you make all the symlinks relative?  That would do the trick.

Assuming that on the NFS server (1.2.3.4), you have the following mounted (different physical drives possible)

```
/media/drive1/pictures/
/media/drive2/pictures/
/media/drive3/pictures/
/media/drive4/pictures/
# ...
```

In the script change your ln line from

```
 ln -s "$item" "$target"
```

to read

```
 ln -s "../${item#/media/}" "$target"
```

This would create your symlinks in the format of

```
../drive1/pictures/...
```

Since you mention it's a private network and security isn't a concern, you can set the exports to

```
### /etc/exports
/media *(ro,async)
```

Then on the client boxes that mount the NFS

```
mkdir -p foo; mount 1.2.3.4:/media foo
```

In foo you will now see share, drive1, drive2, drive3, drive4, ...

So in effect you've mounted the whole media directory on your client, and the symlinks are relative so they would work fine.  The amount of change needed is pretty minimal, the `${item#/media/}` syntax may or may not be supported by your version of bash, any equivalent would do (you can use sed commands, awk, or anything you're familiar with to chop off the /media/).

The only problem left is unique names, if you have the following folder or file

```
/media/drive1/pictures/same_name1
/media/drive2/pictures/same_name1
```

The current code

```
if [ ! -d "$target" ]; then
    ln -s "$item" "$target"
    chown -h lsc:lsc "$target"
fi
```

Would skip creating a symlink after the first target is encountered.  So you may have files that are missing symlinks purely because the name is already used in another drive.

You would need to modify your symlink name to append some kind of unique identifier for these cases.

```
if [ -d "$target" ]; then
    #extract out the "drive1" part from $item and prepend it to target 
    target="$(echo item | sed -e 's!/media/\([^/]*\)/pictures.*!\1!g')_${target}"
fi

if [ ! -d "$target" ]; then
    ln -s "$item" "$target"
    chown -h lsc:lsc "$target"
fi
```

Answer (score 5):

This approach will not work with NFS mounted shares. Symbolic links only contain a path to another file or directory on the originating system where they're being shared from. Unless you take care to make the links relative or to duplicate the same directory structures on remote systems as the originator of the share, they simply will not work.

I cannot think of any method that will allow the directory structure as you've described through NFS, and give you the functionality that you're looking for.

You might want to take a look at the advanced features of automounting, specifically this page titled: [Setting advanced automount map options](http://osr507doc.sco.com/en/NetAdminG/autoT.advanced_map_options.html).

#### References

- [ArchLinux AutoFS Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/autofs)
- [AutoFS Project Page](http://www.autofs.org/)

Comment: You could use *bind mount* instead of symlinks! Look at [my anser](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/412473/27653)

Answer (score 2):

#### Yes, but...

As correctly answered by [slm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/135058/27653), you could not *dereference* symlinks by *nfs server*, but as correctly pointed out by [alejandro izquierdo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/372937/27653), you could use ***bind mount*** to make the job:

1. Ensure to mount your `VFAT` or `NTFS` with option `uid=XXX` to match correct user (*lsc*).

   ```
   mount -o uid=XXX,gid=YYY /dev/sdX1 /media/drive1
   ```
2. Now you could replace your *`for item in...`* loop by something like:

   ```
   for item in /media/"drive1/pictures"/*
   do
       target="/media/share/pictures/$(basename "$item")"
       if [ ! -d "$target" ]; then
           mkdir "$target"
           mount --bind "$item" "$target"
       fi
   done
   ```

   Of course, this have to be done with ***root*** privileges! By using sudo or maybe from `udev` scripts...
3. Care to umount the bind (`umount "$target"`) before umounting the real source (`/media/driveX`) **and** don't forget to remove the mountpoint (`rmdir "$target"`).

   Nota: you could `rmdir /media/share/pictures/*`, then will see some:

   ```
   rmdir: failed to remove '/media/share/pictures/drive1/': Device or resource busy
   ```

   which are not harmfull, then unused empty dirs will be removed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a bind type mount, that is better than links in many situations, in fstab file you can put:

```
/source    /dest    none defaults,bind   0   0
```

Answer (score 1):

It works with NFS export options 'nohide,crossmnt'

1. /dev/sdc1 mounted on /shared
2. /dev/sdd1 mounted on /shared/disk2
3. /etc/exports has the mount option *nohide* and *crossmnt*
4. Now reload exports with *exportfs -ra*

Ref: https://linux.die.net/man/5/exports